# Reducing a 2nd order system of ODEs to a 1st order system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I need to numerically solve the following system of ODEs:

$$x''(t)=- \frac{3x}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$
$$y''(t)=- \frac{3y}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$

I know that I must convert to a system of 1st order equations but I am having trouble doing so...Could someone provide me with a starting point? This problem is called the "one-body problem" apparently but I cannot find much about it as all the hits I'm getting involve the 2 body problem...Help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that needs to be done to convert to a system of first order ODEs is to play some games with your notation, in this case it's particularly simple because you don't have any first derivatives.

So let's say we choose to define
\begin{align}
x_1 &\equiv x, \\
x_2 &\equiv x_1', \\
y_1 &\equiv y, \\
y_2 &\equiv y_1'.
\end{align}

So now your system system will consist of 4, first order, coupled ODEs in your 4 variables. It will look like the following
\begin{align}
x_1' &= x_2, \\
x_2' &= \frac{-3x_1}{\left( x_1^2 + y_1^2 \right)^{3/2}}, \\
y_1' &= ..., \\
y_2' &= ... .
\end{align}

Are you now able to write down the final two equations in your system?

Now you can just numerically solve these 4 ODEs for each of your 4 variables; $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$. You can then relate these back to your original $x, y$ through their respective definitions.

Comment: Ok so the last equations will be, $y_1' = y_2,
y_2' = \frac{-3y_1}{( x_1^2 + y_1^2 )^{3/2}}$

Comment: @sjf2468 that's correct :)

Comment: Now I have a new dilemma. I need to use the predictor corrector method(ie predictor AB2 and corrector AM2 to solve the problem. I am having trouble wrapping my head around what the algorithm intails...Will I need to solve the above system at each step?

Comment: @sjf2468 that's usually how these things work. I'm not familiar with that particular method, but you will need to solve the system to give predicted values of $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$, and then solve it once again (presumably using the predicted values of these variables) to produce the corrected values of these variables. Then you will need to do this at every time step. Also if my answer was what you were after feel free to accept it :)

Comment: It seems that this being a 2d case is confusing me. Will the numerical method transfer to a 2d case without changing?